how can i get rid of this particular error in react native expo
how can I get past this error code in react native expo : 'window.addEventListener if not a function (it is undefined)'
I am currently trying to make use of the clerk authentication API , its stating that its an uncaught error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
